# b) If $ det A = 0 $ then $ Kerf $ contains a vector different from the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : R^n → R^n$ be a linear mapping and let $A = [f]$ be the matrix of f. Decide whether the
following statements are true or not:

a) If $ Kerf $ contains a vector different from the zero vector, then $ det A = 0 $.

b) If $ det A = 0 $ then $ Kerf $ contains a vector different from the zero vector

My opinion is that if  $ det A = 0 $ it means vectors which span $ Kerf $ are dependent and contains vector different from the zero vector but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both (a) and (b) are true.

For (a): if $v \in\ker f$ and $v \neq 0$, then $Av=0$ thus $0$ is an eigenvalue and determinant is $0$.

For (b): if $\det A=0$, then $A$ is not invertible. Thus columns of $A$ are not linearly independent, hence $Ax=0$ has a non-trivial solution. So $\ker f$ must contain a non-zero vector.

Comment: it is clear thanks